# Laravel Vue Multiple image Upload failing on for each with a NULL value

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, multiple-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images in Laravel but, one, am unable to upload more than one in the upload dialog box that comes with HTML and two, in my dump and die test before the foreach, I am getting a NULL value. I am new to Laravel and vue so I am sure it is a matter of something simple but for the life of my I don't know what I am missing. First off, I am running the post request in the web.php file which I am not sure if that is a good idea or not. Anyhow, my scripts fail before I can even upload a file.
Here is the code I have so far.

web.php

```
Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    $uploadedFiles = $request->pics;


    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $file) {
        dd($file);

        $file->store('dummy');
    }

    return response(['status' => 'success'], 200);
});
```

app.js (void of code I felt was irrelevant)

```
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");

import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";

window.Form = Form;

Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);

import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

let routes = [
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        component: require("./components/Dashboard.vue").default
    },
    
    
    {
        path: "/users",
        component: require("./components/Users.vue").default
    },
    {
        path: "/tasks",
        component: require("./components/Tasks.vue").default
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
});

Vue.component(
    "dashboard-component",
    require("./components/Dashboard.vue").default
);

Vue.component("file-upload", require("./components/FileUpload.vue").default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router
});
```

FileUpload.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input class="" type="file" @change="fieldChange" />
        <button class="btn btn-success float-right mt-3" @click="uploadFile">
            Upload
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            attachments: [],
            formImage: new FormData()
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fieldChange(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let selectedFiles = e.target.files;

            if (!selectedFiles.length) {
                return false;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
                this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
            console.log(this.attachments);
        },
        uploadFile() {
            this.formImage.append("task_image", this.attachments);

            const config = {
                headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
            };

            axios
                .post("/upload", this.formImage, config)
                .then(response => {
                    // success
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    // fail
                });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    }
};
</script>
```

Task.vue (In its entirety. I didn't know if something in here was causing the conflict so I included everything).

```
<template>
    <div class="custom-container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div
                        class="card-header text-white"
                        style="background-color: #605ca8;"
                    >
                        <h3 class="card-title">Tasks</h3>

                        <div class="card-tools">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Add New Task
                            </button>
                            <!-- <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
              </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div
                        class="table-x-y card-body table-responsive p-0"
                        style="max-height: 600px;"
                    >
                        <table class="table table-hover text-wrap">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Task</th>
                                    <th>Priority</th>
                                    <th>Assigned To</th>
                                    <th>Assigned By</th>
                                    <th>Date Assigned</th>
                                    <th>Due By:</th>
                                    <th>Task Desc.</th>
                                    <th>Images</th>
                                    <!-- <th>Notes</th> -->
                                    <th>finished</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
                                    <td>{{ task.task_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ task.task_priority }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ task.task_assigned_to }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ task.task_assigned_by }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ task.created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ task.task_to_be_completed_date }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td
                                        style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 301px;"
                                    >
                                        {{ task.task_description }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img
                                            style="max-width: 150px;"
                                            src="/img/molding.jpg"
                                            alt
                                        />
                                        {{ task.task_image }}
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td>{{ task.task_notes }}</td> -->
                                    <td>{{ task.task_finished }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ task.task_status }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a
                                            href="#"
                                            class="badge badge-primary p-2 mb-3"
                                            @click="editModal(task)"
                                        >
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        <a
                                            @click="deleteTask(task.id)"
                                            href="#"
                                            class="badge badge-danger p-2"
                                        >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                        </a>
                                        <file-upload></file-upload>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateTask() : createTask()">
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div
                class="modal fade"
                id="addNew"
                tabindex="-1"
                aria-labelledby="addNewLabel"
                aria-hidden="true"
            >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5
                                class="modal-title"
                                v-show="!editmode"
                                id="addNewLabel"
                            >
                                Add New Task
                            </h5>
                            <h5
                                class="modal-title"
                                v-show="editmode"
                                id="addNewLabel"
                            >
                                Update Task Information
                            </h5>

                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"
                            >
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input
                                    id="task_name"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_name"
                                    name="task_name"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Task Name"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_name'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                />
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_name"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select
                                    id="task_priority"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_priority"
                                    name="task_priority"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_priority'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                >
                                    <option value
                                        >Select a Priority Level</option
                                    >
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_priority"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input
                                    id="task_description"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_description"
                                    name="task_description"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Task Description"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_description'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                />
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_description"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input
                                    id="task_assigned_by"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_assigned_by"
                                    name="task_assigned_by"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Assigned By"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_assigned_by'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                />
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_assigned_by"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input
                                    id="task_assigned_to"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_assigned_to"
                                    name="task_assigned_to"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Assigned To"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_assigned_to'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                    value="form.user.id"
                                />
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_assigned_to"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="task_to_be_completed_date"
                                    >Due:</label
                                >
                                <input
                                    id="task_to_be_completed_date"
                                    type="date"
                                    v-model="form.task_to_be_completed_date"
                                    name="task_to_be_completed_date"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Due: "
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_to_be_completed_date'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                />
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_to_be_completed_date"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select
                                    id="task_status"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_status"
                                    name="task_status"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_status'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                >
                                    <option value>Select Task Status</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                                    <option value="Incomplete"
                                        >Incomplete</option
                                    >
                                </select>
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_status"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  id="task_notes"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_notes"
                  name="task_notes"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Notes"
                  :class="{
                            'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                            'task_notes')
                        }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_notes"></has-error>
              </div>-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select
                                    id="task_finished"
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="form.task_finished"
                                    name="task_finished"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_finished'
                                        )
                                    }"
                                >
                                    <option value
                                        >Select finished status</option
                                    >
                                    <option value="1">Finished</option>
                                    <option value="0">Unfinished</option>
                                </select>
                                <has-error
                                    :form="form"
                                    field="task_status"
                                ></has-error>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                <input id="upload-file" class="form-control" type="file" @change="fieldChange" />
                <button class="btn btn-success float-right mt-3" @click="uploadFile">Upload</button>
              </div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="btn btn-primary"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                            >
                                Close
                            </button>
                            <button
                                v-show="editmode"
                                type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-success"
                            >
                                Update
                            </button>
                            <button
                                v-show="!editmode"
                                type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-primary"
                            >
                                Create New Task
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            editmode: true,
            tasks: {},
            attachments: [],
            formImage: new FormData(),
            form: new Form({
                id: "",
                task_name: "",
                task_description: "",
                task_assigned_by: "",
                task_assigned_to: "",
                task_to_be_completed_date: "",
                task_priority: "",
                // task_notes: "",
                task_status: "",
                task_finished: ""
                // task_image: "",
            })
        };
    },
    methods: {
        updateTask() {
            this.$Progress.start();
            this.form
                .put("api/task/" + this.form.id)
                .then(() => {
                    // successfull
                    $("#addNew").modal("hide");
                    Swal.fire(
                        "Updated",
                        "Task information updated.",
                        "success"
                    );
                    this.$Progress.finish();
                    Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    // Unsuccessfull
                    this.$Progress.fail();
                });
        },
        editModal(task) {
            this.editmode = true;
            this.form.reset();
            $("#addNew").modal("show");
            this.form.fill(task);
        },
        newModal() {
            this.editmode = false;
            this.form.reset();
            $("#addNew").modal("show");
        },
        deleteTask(id) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
                cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
            }).then(result => {
                // Send request to the server
                if (result.value) {
                    this.form
                        .delete("api/task/" + id)
                        .then(() => {
                            Swal.fire(
                                "Deleted!",
                                "Task has been deleted.",
                                "success"
                            );

                            Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            Swal.fire(
                                "Failed",
                                "Something went wrong.",
                                "warning"
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
        },
        loadTasks() {
            axios.get("api/task").then(({ data }) => (this.tasks = data.data));
        },
        createTask() {
            this.$Progress.start();
            this.form
                .post("api/task")
                .then(() => {
                    Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
                    $("#addNew").modal("hide");
                    toast.fire({
                        icon: "success",
                        title: "Task Created successfully"
                    });
                    this.$Progress.finish();
                    this.target.reset();
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.$Progress.fail();
                    //   toast.fire({
                    //     icon: "error",
                    //     title: "The Task was not created.",
                    //   });
                });
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.loadTasks();
        // setInterval(() => this.loadUsers(), 3000);
        Fire_event.$on("AfterCreate", () => {
            this.loadTasks();
        });
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    }
};
</script>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to upload to my sql server locally. In my .env file, I have FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public specified pointing to the config/filesystem.php public route pre-specified in that file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here

1. You are preventing the default event action for the *change* event on `<input type="file">`. Don't do that. **Remove this line** from your `fieldChange` method

   ```js
   e.preventDefault()
   ```
2. `Content-type` headers for `multipart/form-data` requests also need to include mime-boundary tokens. These are added automatically by the browser when using `FormData` so you should not be setting them manually. Change your Axios call to

   ```js
   axios.post("/upload", this.formImage) // no config required
   ```
3. You are adding an array of files to your `FormData`. This isn't how you add multiple files. Instead, you must call `append()` multiple times. When posting arrays of data to PHP, the field name should also be suffixed with `[]`

   ```js
   this.attachments.forEach(file => {
     this.formImage.append("task_image[]", file)
   })
   ```

   See https://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.multiple.php
4. Your PHP code should be looking for `task_image` in the request files, not `pics`

   ```php
   $uploadedFiles = $request->file('task_image');
   // or maybe
   $uploadedFiles = $request->task_image;
   // I don't know Laravel and the docs are useless for multiple file uploads
   ```

Comment: Thank you Phil. I implemented the suggested changes but I am still getting the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error. I am stumped.

Comment: I don't know Laravel at all so perhaps you need `$uploadedFiles = $request->task_image;`

Comment: That helped a little. The error changed hahaha. Now I am getting: message: "Call to a member function store() on string" In my dd() call I got object_file in the green. :)